# CartFlows: Force add to cart redirection to cart page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

In my WooCommerce website, I have installed [WooCommerce Checkout & Funnel Builder by CartFlows](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cartflows/) plugin to make my WooCommerce checkout page more neath, but for some reason if I click add to cart in my site, it redirects to Checkout page not in cart pages. I'm thinking that the problem is the CartFlows plugins cause the steps of CartFlow: as you can see in the screenshot, it is only 2 pages:

[image]

How can I make my add to cart button redirect to cart page.

In the screenshot, you can see that it redirects to the checkout page upon clicking on add to cart button:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following code snippet, without any guaranty:

```php
add_filter ('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', function( $url, $adding_to_cart ) {
    return wc_get_cart_url();
}, 999999, 2 );
```

It could work with Cartflow plugin.

Comment: sorry im newbie in this industry but i have an idea what the code is but i dont know where  i place that code?

Comment: You can add the code in your child theme functions.php file. Or you can upload/activate [Code Snippets plugin *By Code Snippets Pro*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/), where you will be able to add the code, if you don't use a child theme.

Comment: wow it work, thank you. such a big help